# Should MVC Bundling allow multiple CDN paths to be included for each file in the bundle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I would like to bundle 2 css files related to Twitter Bootstraps.

```
"~/Content/Themes/Base/CSS/bootstrap-theme.css"
"~/Content/Themes/Base/CSS/bootstrap.css"
```

Each of the file has a separate URL to its CDN:

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
```

How can I provide 2 CDN paths to 2 separate css files in the same StyleBundle?
Do I need to create 2 StyleBundles separately, each includes a single css file? This seems to be counter productive for the effort of bundling.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will bundle as follow:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapTheme", "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css").Include(
                "~/Content/Themes/Base/CSS/bootstrap-theme.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap", "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css").Include(
                "~/Content/Themes/Base/CSS/bootstrap.css"));
```

Its not counterproductive because you need to understand why MVC allows you to bundle CDN Paths:
When bundling with the CDN, the CDN tag will be referenced in production, and the local version will be referenced when debugging.

In your webconfig you can set which one gets rendered: 
Set `<compilation debug="true"/>` to use the local file, and `<compilation debug="false"/>` to use your CDN.

To call this in your view: (Note: what you put between the () here must be the same as the first parameter above in the StyleBundle.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapTheme")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
```

Comment: If bundling means combining more than one files together, conditionally switching tags does not qualify as bundling. But I guess, it's just more convenient this way rather than introducing another thing simply for CDN conditional switching.

Comment: @Believe2014 I do see your point. I guess its just the way Microsoft decided to do it =(  You could probably make your own library do what your wanting. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Add it as shown below:

```
url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600");
```

Comment: Your answer does not address MVC bundling feature. Nor is it relevant to the context. A future researcher of this question won't be able to use the `url()` function at all without knowing whether it is C# or Javascript and how it fits into the context of compiling and bundling static files.